# Examples of $f \in C^2[a,b]$ where the total variation of $f$ on $[a,x]$ is not in $C^2[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is of bounded variation; define $V(x) = V[f;a,x]$ (the total variation of $f$ on $[a,x]$.

I want to show that $V \in C^1[a,b]$. Since $f'$ is continuous, hence bounded on $[a,b]$ I have that $f$ is absolutely continuous. From that I have $V' = |f'|$, and since $f'$ is continuous, $|f'| = V'$ must be as well, correct?

If instead $f \in C^2[a,b]$, I'm looking for an example $f$ where $V \not\in C^2[a,b]$. From the above result, I think that means I should be looking for an $f$ where $f''$ is continuous but $|f'|'$ is not.

Thanks for any examples and/or suggestions on how to construct such an $f$.

Comment: It's not a homework, I'm working problems in preparation for a test. My (perhaps faulty) reasoning was this: if $f \in C^1$, then $V'' = (\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f'(t)dt)' = f''$ so $V''$ would also be $C^2$. Hopefully this betrays some error or misunderstanding of mine that may be corrected.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable

Comment: I see. I sloppily dropped the abs. value. So $V[f;a,x] = \int_a^x |f'|$ would be correct.

Comment: Agreed. Let me revise the question to deal with the first part as ell...

Comment: With the absolute value this would be correct (as in Wikipedia).  I could give you an example of a function you asked about, but i prefer to let you revise the definitions first, sorry.  It makes no sense to give an answer before the question is fully understood.

Comment: I think you are close to finding an answer with your last edit.  If you do not want to take a guess, try to look for $f'$ first.  Call it $g=f'$.  You want $g$ such that $g'$ is continuous, but $|g|'$ is not continuous or not defined everywhere.

Comment: Just in case, be sure to understand the total variation intuitively, and not only formally.  Think of an easy mountain hike.  Apart from the horizontal distance travelled, you might be interested in knowing the total accent and decent.

Comment: I have removed my comments not relevant to the last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $x\mapsto x^2$ on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Thank you for helping me to see it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x$ on $[0,2]$ would do the trick. Then $f'(x) = x-1$, $f''(x) = 1$ so $f \in C^2$. But $|f'|' = \pm 1$ on $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$ respectively, so $|f'|' = V''$ is not continuous.